# Get record between two time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have a table with two time column `[StartTime]` and `[EndTime]`

Table record contains `StartTime 07:00` and `EndTime 13:30`

I want to retreive the record if the user select `@StartTime = 09:00` and `@EndTime = 11:00`

`SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE [StartTime] >= '09:00' AND [EndTime] <= '11:00'`

Does not return any record.

What should i do with my query?

Comment: What is the type of the column of `StartTime` and `EndTime`? `char`/`varchar`? ...

Comment: but if you have 9:00 and 11:00 in your table,then your proposed query must work out

Comment: What if StartTime and EndTime is on different days, is that possible? For instance, StartTime is 22:00 and EndTime is 06:00, what then?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i added new column `[StartDate]` and `[EndDate]` just in case this scenario happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TBL 
WHERE  
('09:00' between [StartTime] AND [EndTime]) or ('11:00' between [StartTime] AND [EndTime])
```

Comment: this will not catch rows where starttime = 09:30 and endtime = 10:00 although they are both within 09:00 and 11:00

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you're looking for rows that *overlap* with the query range. You can use the following paradigm to find overlaps:

```
where [StartTime] <= @EndTime
and [EndTime] >= @StartTime
```

Consider the following illustration:

```
MATCHING ROWS

Query:     |----------------------------------|
                      |----|  
   |-----------------------|
                      |-----------------------------|
   |------------------------------------------------|

NON-MATCHING ROWS

Query:     |----------------------------------|
   |---|
                                                    |----|
```

Note that in every matching case, the End time is on or after the beginning of the query and the Start time is on or before the end of the query.